# anchor href does not display properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to navigate to another page section with anchor tag  from current page /contact.html. The problem I am having here is that the result view do not correspond to the start of the  container. Upon searching online, I suspect that it was because the web site components are dynamically loaded and do not have fixed height for the image slider.

Nonetheless, I did not find any solution to this problem yet. Hope someone can help me in this issue.

Note: The anchor tag work perfectly as it is if it is used in the index.html page itself.

For code reference and better illustrations, please refer to following link. This is exactly the problem I am facing.

```html
<a href="http://themehats.com/themes/jango/onepage-4.html#features">Click here</a>
<a href="http://themehats.com/themes/jango/onepage-4.html#clients">Click here</a>
<a href="http://themehats.com/themes/jango/onepage-4.html#pricing">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you better.

Comment: Do you use fixed positions? Lazyload on images?

Comment: @Tro i have updated the link for better reference. that is the template i am currently using.

Comment: @romuleald its a fixed position header + slider as shown in the new updated link.

Comment: With the fixed position, you will never achieve to the correct position, because your content will be under. You'll need javascript to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comments, you have a fixed position on your header, so you need to calculate in `JS` your header height.

If you have jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click' function(){
    var $link = $(location.href);
    var position = $link.offset().top - $('#header').height()
    $(window.animate({scrollTop: position},{duration: 500})
});
```

For onload with an anchor in the URL:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $link = $(location.href);
    if($link.length {
        var position = $$link.offset().top - $('#header').height()
        $(window.animate({scrollTop: position},{duration: 500})
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am navigating the anchor tag from another page to the section of this page, not navigating the anchor tag within this page. So i suppose $('a').on('click') will not work?